# Why does the high pressure (small) line make loud noise when new A/C is running?

Tags: hvac

Had a new 5 Ton AC installed (compressor and coil matched system) and now when the system runs there is a loud noise in the small high pressure copper line when the system is running. Cooling seems just OK. Any ideas on what it could be? charge or other issues?

Comment: If the loud noise is like whistling, would suspect a leak.  Loud noises can be almost anything, but the type of sound it makes would probably help.

Comment: You might want to get with the installer while the warranty is still in effect.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a high pressure limit, if a short line set the system could be actually over charged and a mechanical limit can cause a high pressure limit and they can be quite loud. But they still cool because of the limit controlling the flow.

Comment: Call the installer and have them worry about it, it should not do that. For your own edification I would suggest putting on a heavy set of gloves and grab the line at several points and see if the noise stops, if so it needs to be mounted tighter. The best solution is to have the pro's fix there problem you paid them to install it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It is kind of a whoosh or shu noise, you can hear it in the whole basement.